# Count how many rows are in a BigQuery table using Python

Tags: python, google-bigquery

For a short summary - I want to set a variable equal to the amount of rows present or amount of data entries present in a table.

I am running a query in my Python script that counts the amount of devices that have been used in my app through the past week. I do this by counting the distinct serial numbers. Currently I am using this query.

```
#standardsql
SELECT count(distinct serial)
FROM `dataworks-356fa.FirebaseArchive.test2` 
Where (PeripheralType = 1 or PeripheralType = 2 or PeripheralType = 12)
AND EXTRACT(WEEK FROM createdAt) = EXTRACT(WEEK FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) - 1
AND serial != 'null'
```

I am then sending this result to slack at a later point in my python script with this code.

```
with open('Count_BB_Serial_weekly.json', 'r') as lowfile:
  low = json.load(lowfile)

low1 = low["f0_"]
```

`f0_` = the amount of distinct serial numbers counted

However, now I want to add a function that I can also see the serial numbers which have been used along with the amount of different serial numbers used. The query to list the serial numbers is similar to the above just without the `count(distinct)` part. Is there a way that I can set `low1` equal to the amount of rows in the table because I can not run a count function that also lists the serial numbers. Hopefully you can follow along with this. If there is any confusion I will address it in the comments.

Thank you!

Comment: I just realized that this is actually pulling the value from a JSON not the bigquery table. So is it possible to count the amount of entries present in a JSON?

Comment: You can count entries in a JSON in python by using the `len` operator. Still, from what I understood from your question, this json is the result of a query ran in BQ. This being the case I wonder if it would be better to bring another field in the results (such as `f1_`) containing the total rows processed already (let BQ do the work, not python).

Comment: You can count entries in a JSON in python by using the `len` operator. Still, from what I understood from your question, this JSON is the result of a query ran in BQ. This being the case, I wonder if it would be better to bring another field in the results (such as `f1_`) containing the total rows processed already (let BQ do the work, not python).

Comment: So you're saying that I can add a line to my query that would add a column to the table that has the value of rows processed?

Comment: Just answered with an example. Not sure though why you tagged the question with "mysql" and "bigquery". I suppose by the question title that you are working with BigQuery and not MySQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably can already bring this result in BigQuery. For instance:

```
#standardSQL
WITH data AS(
  SELECT '1' AS serial UNION ALL
  SELECT '2' as serial UNION ALL
  SELECT '3' AS serial UNION ALL
  SELECT '1' AS serial
)

SELECT
  ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT serial) distinct_serials,
  ARRAY_LENGTH(ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT serial)) total_serials
FROM
  data
```

Results in:

```
[
  {
    "distinct_serials": [
      "2",
      "1",
      "3"
    ],
    "total_serials": "3"
  }
]
```

Or in your query, it would be something like:

```
#standardsql
SELECT
    ARRAY_AGG(serial) serials,
    ARRAY_LENGTH(ARRAY_AGG(serial)) total_serials
FROM(
SELECT distinct serial AS serial
FROM `dataworks-356fa.FirebaseArchive.test2` 
Where (PeripheralType = 1 or PeripheralType = 2 or PeripheralType = 12)
AND EXTRACT(WEEK FROM createdAt) = EXTRACT(WEEK FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) - 1
AND serial != 'null')
```

Results should be something like:

`[{"serials": ["serial_1", "serial_2", (...)], "total_serials": 10}]`

You would have an ARRAY with the serials and another field with its total entries.

Comment: Im trying to run this but Bigquery is giving me an error that serial is an unrecognized name in ARRAY_AGG(). How is that possible?